# Why doesn't Google Maps have bicycle directions for Barcelona?

Tags: google-maps

For Barcelona, Google Maps has driving, public transport and walking directions.  However, the button for cycling directions is grayed out.  Is this feature only available in certain places?

Comment: I ask the same for Portugal!

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the area does not support this method of navigation in Google Maps.

Looking at the location you mention Google Maps is reporting that "Cycling is not available".

You could try out [OpenCycleMaps](http://www.opencyclemap.org/) powered by [OpenStreetMaps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I agree it's odd. Device is a normal web browser, and location is the center of the city.

Comment: It looks like cycling simply isn't available for the area. You can try out http://www.opencyclemap.org/

Comment: How can an area be requested for cycling maps on the Google Maps service?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - looks like is built on Google anyhow,

http://com-shi-va.lameva.barcelona.cat/en/bicycle